# regex: match a group but return a different string

Tags: regex, regex-group

Consider the following strings

```
C 1
D 2.2
Y 1
Z 2.2
```

I need a regex to match both and return the 1 or 2, respectively. The following regex works:

`((C|Y) (\d)|(D|Z) (\d).(?:\d))`

What's more important: I also need to know whether (C|Y) or (D|Z) was matched.

I plan to do that in the calling code (which is python). I could test whether the string is C,Y,D or Z but that approach is not extensible. I want the regex to return A in the first capturing group if either C or Y have been matched and B if either D or Z have been matched. That way, I only need to check for A or B in the calling code and I can easily extend the classes by more members. Is there a way to do that?

I also read about string replacements using regex. I don't think that is the correct tool for me, because it would involve creating another string with replaced text (if I understood correctly). That's not what I need.

Comment: Speaking about replacing, did you mean https://regex101.com/r/UnNTh5/1? If not, do you mean you want to know which group matched, and once you know which one matched, `(C|Y)` or `(D|Z)`, return the `1` or `2`?

Comment: Also, check https://ideone.com/5NDTTi

Comment: Do you need help with this? If yes, please provide feedback.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah! Yep, the code you provided works perfectly! I didn't know that unmatched groups in the conditional still contribute to the group index - meaning that I can just check if the second or the fourth group matched (just like you did in your code). If you make you comment an answer, I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match the string using your regex and then check which group matched. Once you know which one did, you may return any value you wish.

```
import re

text = '''C 1
D 2.2
Y 1
Z 2.2'''

for s in text.splitlines():
  print("--- '" + s + "' ---")
  m = re.search(r'((C|Y) (\d)|(D|Z) (\d)\.(?:\d))', s)
  if m and m.group(2):
    print(m.group(3))
  elif m and m.group(4):
    print(m.group(5))
  else:
    print("NO MATCH!")
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5NDTTi), output:

```
--- 'C 1' ---
1
--- 'D 2.2' ---
2
--- 'Y 1' ---
1
--- 'Z 2.2' ---
2
```